# Websockets connecting multiple times in React JS + Electron NodeJS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I have an application built in Electron JS, that uses React and websockets.

I'm calling the server in a renderer thread with this code:

```
const host = 'http://localhost:3000';

const socket = io(host);
const apiClient = new APIClient(socket);
apiClient.someMethod(...);
```

This code IS NOT inside a React JS component. It's on index.tsx, which is called only once. If I put a console.log in that code it only gets printed once.

In the server I have a code similar to this one:

```
    io.on("connection", socket => {
      // getting sesionUserId

      console.log("Client connected. User id: ", sessionUserId);
```

The code doesn't seem to work and in the server I get this log:

```
Client connected. User id:  5
Client connected. User id:  5
Client connected. User id:  5
Client connected. User id:  5
Client connected. User id:  5
... etc
```

Which seem to happen is that websockets are connecting all the time. Why could be this? I don't have much experience with Electron. It looks like the client can connect with the server, but for some reason it retries to connect. Also, when I try to speak to the server I don't get an answer (which I guess it's because it's reconnecting all the time).

Is there any restriction on Electron JS that it prevents websockets to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using different version of socketIO on client and server, try to make them of same major version. This happened to me when I had different version where I had version 2.X.X at client and 3.X.X at server. so I made both version of socketIO for both server and client to 2.X.X and everything started working fine.
i.e I used 'socket-io-client' module at client of version 2.X.X at client side
and I used 'socket-io' module at server of version 2.X.X and no more multiple websocket connection was being formed.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @hhaamm glad to be of help :>